# create coverage report from script

Tags: .net, code-coverage, dotcover

I use dotCover for code coverage, and it's good, but the results appear to be written in a proprietary format, which I cannot parse.

I want to create a script that analyses my .Net code base and returns the (say) 20 classes with the lowest code coverage in a format that I can read (xml, plain text, json, ...). Does anyone know how to do this, either in dotCover or other tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover)  and [ReportGenerator](http://reportgenerator.codeplex.com).
OpenCover generates a XML coverage report. ReportGenerator transforms this report into HTML, XML (readable) and Latex.
See this blogpost for more details:
http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/6/21/code-coverage-testing-with-opencover-and-partcover

Comment: Thanks for the suggestino, will take a look